# Help me understand this conditional expectation problem, please!

Tags: probability

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be the numbers on two independent die rolls.
Let $X$ be the minimum of the two rolls, and let $Y$ be the maximum.

I need to calculate $E(Y|X=x)$ and I have a solution from the textbook I'm working from, but it is missing some steps and I can't figure out how they are getting to the final answer. The textbook does not seem to have any similar examples I can work from and I have absolutely no idea what process they are using to arrive at the answer.

I've determined that:

$$  P(X=x)=P(X\ge x)-P(X\ge x+1)= \left({{7-x}\over {6}} \right)^2- \left({{6-x}\over {6}} \right)^2 = {{13-2x}\over 36} $$

and also that:

$$ P(Y=y|X=x)= \left\{ \begin{matrix}
{P(X=x, Y=y)\over P(X=x)} = {{1\over36}\over {{13-2x}\over 36}} = {1\over{13-2x}} & \text{if } y=x \\
{P(X=x, Y=y)\over P(X=x)} = {{2\over36}\over {{13-2x}\over 36}} = {2\over{13-2x}} & \text{if } y>x \\
\end{matrix}
 \right.   $$

and this is where I'm stuck... The next step in the solution is:

$$ E(Y|X=x)= {x\over{13-2x}} + \sum_{y=x+1}^6{y \cdot {2\over {13-2x} }} $$

I'm not sure what they've done to get here. I'm not even sure how to expand the summation they've concocted, and I'm also not sure how and why they've concocted it.

From there, they say that:

$$ E(Y|X=x)={1\over {13-2x}} \left[ x + 2\cdot{ {(x+7)(6-x)}\over{2} } \right] = {{42-x^2}\over{13-2x}} $$

As I have no idea how they've expanded the summation, what it means, or why it's there, I have no idea how to get to this point right here, even if I take their expression for $E(Y|X=x)$ as given, and I can't attack this from the other direction, as it's not obvious to me how to go backwards, either.

What I would like is for someone to explain precisely what is going on here. How can the summation above can be expanded? How would I even know to set that expression up the way it's been set up?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, how do they get $$E(Y|X=x)= {x\over{13-2x}} + \sum_{y=x+1}^6{y \cdot {2\over {13-2x} }}?$$

They are using the basic definition of expected value for a discrete distribution, informally, the sum of each $y$ value multiplied by its respective probability: $$E(Y)=\sum_{\text{all y} } y\times p(Y=y)$$

So in this case, $$E(Y|X=x)=x\times p(Y=x)+\sum_{y>x}y\times p(Y>x)$$

For the sum, $Y$ can take values from $x+1$ up to 6, and the probability $p(Y>x)$ is the same expression $\frac{2}{13-2z}$ for each of these $Y$ values. So we can write this as $$E(Y|X=x)= x\times{1\over{13-2x}} + \sum_{y=x+1}^6{y \cdot {2\over {13-2x} }}$$$$= {x\over{13-2x}}  + \frac{2}{13-2x} \sum_{y=x+1}^6y$$

For the next step, the summation, they have used the idea of the sum of $n$ terms of an arithmetic progression being $$\frac n2(\text{first term}+\text{last term})$$

In this case there are $6-x$ terms, with the first term $x+1$ and the last term $6$, and that's where the factor $$\frac{(x+7)(6-x)}{2}$$ comes from.

The rest is just factorisation and simplification.

I hope this helps.